# Brace expansion does not work for less than 2 arguments

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

I was expecting brace expansion to work for any number of arguments. However, for n=1 I get the following:

```
$ find models/nsf-projects-{7}*
models/nsf-projects-{7}.rdf
```

For n>1 expansion occurs as expected, e.g.:

```
$ find models/nsf-projects-{6,7}*
find: ‘models/nsf-projects-6*’: No such file or directory
find: ‘models/nsf-projects-7*’: No such file or directory
```

I have browsed the GNU manuals a bit, but have not found the requirement to >1 arguments stated explicitly anywhere.

Q: Is n>1 indeed a requirement for brace expansion? If so, why is it useful?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, [n > 1 is an explicit requirement](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion):

> A correctly-formed brace expansion must contain unquoted opening and closing braces, and at least one unquoted comma or a valid sequence expression. Any incorrectly formed brace expansion is left unchanged.

As for the why - historical reasons, to some extent (though it was copied from `csh` originally, which has the other behaviour). There are commands that take `{}` as a literal argument ([`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), [`parallel`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/parallel), and others with more complex arguments), and also [other uses](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping) of `{}` in the shell language. Because brace expansions are only processed when written literally (and not from variables), there's really no motivation to support degenerate expansions, and some reasons not to.

Answer (score 5):

`man bash` states (emphasis added):

> A correctly-formed  brace  expansion  must contain unquoted opening and closing braces, and **at least one unquoted comma** or a valid sequence expression. Any incorrectly formed brace expansion is left unchanged.

That is also the fifth paragraph in the [Brace Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) section of the bash manual.

I can only speculate as to the motivation, but I suspect it was to allow you to type things which contain `{...}` without the braces vanishing. (That would apply to regular expression repetition operators, to take just one example.)